# How to bring results from rows into columns with respective values in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I currently have the below results table:

| Company ID | External ID | Attribute | Int Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Calls | 3 |
| 1 | 101 | Emails | 14 |
| 1 | 101 | Accounts | 4 |
| 2 | 102 | Calls | 2 |
| 2 | 102 | Emails | 17 |
| 2 | 102 | Accounts | 5 |

And I would like to transform my query results to show as below:

| Company ID | External ID | Calls | Emails | Accounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 3 | 14 | 4 |
| 2 | 102 | 2 | 17 | 5 |

Is this possible and if so, how would I do this? I'm a new SQL user and can't seem to figure this out :)

This is my current query to get my results:

```
SELECT
 ic.company_id,
 ic.external_id,
 icca.attribute, 
 icca.int_value


FROM
 intercom_companies AS ic


LEFT JOIN intercom_companies_custom_attributes AS icca 
ON ic.company_id = icca.company_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot query should work here:

```sql
SELECT
    ic.company_id,
    ic.external_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN icca.attribute = 'Calls'
             THEN icca.int_value END) AS Calls,
    MAX(CASE WHEN icca.attribute = 'Emails'
             THEN icca.int_value END) AS Emails,
    MAX(CASE WHEN icca.attribute = 'Accounts'
             THEN icca.int_value END) AS Accounts
FROM intercom_companies AS ic
LEFT JOIN intercom_companies_custom_attributes AS icca
    ON ic.company_id = icca.company_id
GROUP BY
    ic.company_id,
    ic.external_id;
```